# Searching for a value across 2 tables in Excel 2010, returning yes or no

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have one workbook with 3 separate worksheets

**Sheet 1** contains 2 columns.
Column **A** has a range of unique alphanumeric identifiers.
Column **B** has a range of non-unique numbers.

```
A               B
AU0000ANZHS8    515
AU0000ATBHK3    20
AU0000KFWHZ5    10
AU0000WBCHN7    15
AU0000WBCHO5    10
AU0000WBCHQ0    10
AU000ANZHAL8    515
AU000ANZHAN4    515 
AU000WBCHAS1    25
```

**Sheet 2** contains 1 column.
Column **A** contains a range of 3 non-unique numbers.  Some but not all of these are in **Sheet1**, Column **B**.

```
A
5
10
25
50
100
```

**Sheet 3** contains 2 columns
Column **A** has a range of unique alphanumeric identifiers.  Some of these are the same as those in **Sheet 1**, Column **A**, but not necessarily in the same order.

```
A               
AU0000KFWHZ5        
AU0000WBCHN7        
AU0000ATBHK3    
AU0000WBCHQ0        
AU000ANZHAL8        
AU000ANZHAN4    
AU0000WBCHO5    
AU000WBCHAS1        
AU0000ANZHS8
```

I am trying to enter a Yes/No check into Column **B**.

It should do the following in **B1**:

1. Lookup the value in **Sheet3**, **A1**.
2. Find the matching value in **Sheet1**, Column **A** (in this case A3)
3. Grab the corresponding value in **Sheet1**, Column **B** (is this case **B3**, which is 10)
4. If the value in **B3**, exists in **Sheet2**, Column **A** return "YES", or if not return "NO"

Answer (score 0):

As long as your data really starts on row 1 (ie. you don't have column headers), this should work!:

> =if(isna(vlookup(vlookup(a1,sheet1!a:b,2,false),sheet2!a:a,1,false)),"NO","YES")

This will also return "NO" if the alphanumeric identifier on Sheet3 is NOT also found on Sheet1.